# Spring @Cacheable does not appear to be caching anything

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-cache

I have a microservice that is calling another microservice to see if that microservice is up via Spring Boot Actuator. I'd like to cache the results to avoid having to perform this check every time my microservice is called. So first step would be to cache the the method that performs this check and then have this cache expire after x seconds. So far the first step is not working. I'm expecting to not enter the method that performs the check, but presently I'm entering isAccountConnectorUp() every time. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
@Service
public class DepositService {

  public void getCredit(String message) {
    isAccountConnectorUp();

    sendRequestToStream(message);
  }

  @Cacheable(value = "result", key = "#root.method.name", unless = "#result == true")
  private static boolean isAccountConnectorUp() {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:9996/health";
    boolean isUp = false;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    try {
      String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
      isUp = true;
    } catch (ResourceAccessException exception) {
      throw new DatabaseException(ACCOUNT_CONNECTOR_IS_DOWN);
    }

    return isUp;
  }

}
```

I have added @EnableCaching to my application class.

Comment: This is a _self-call_ and can't be intercepted by Spring. Spring advice only works when you're crossing boundaries between injected objects (where it can intercept and apply it).

Comment: This is a self-call and can be intercepted by Spring. You must use a trick to autowire itself .@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: Ok so what I am trying to do does not seem to be easily do-able with Spring @Cacheable. Is there another caching library that would be better suited given what I am trying to do?

Comment: 1. it won't work on private methods, 2. it won't work on static methods either. 3. it won't work on internal method calls even if you take 1 and 2 into account.

Comment: @M.Deinum We can solve 1 and 3. But 2, we can't not - agreed

Comment: I suggest using spring security to protect method in case you really need that

Comment: Why not? Just make the method non-static. See my answer. However the caching won't work either way, as the result won't be cached in case of an exception (the default) but there is also the `unless == true` which will cache any value but `true`.

Comment: The purpose of method static and non-static ?  1,3 just change library *not change code*

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 3 things wrong with this code.

1. Trying to apply proxy-based AOP on a `private` method
2. Trying to apply proxy-based AOP on a `static` method
3. Doing an internal method call while using proxy-based AOP.

The `@Cacheable` will be applied through the use of AOP. Which when using Spring is by default using proxies. Which means AOP advice will only be applied if a method call passes through the proxy, as you are already inside the proxy, this won't work as it bypasses the proxy.

Now for a proxy-based AOP solution to work the method has to be non-private and not `static`. As currently those cannot be proxied.

So basically you are running into all of those 3. The last one is, somewhat easy, to circumvent, by injecting a reference to yourself and call the method on that.

```java
@Service
public class DepositService {

  @Autowired
  private DepositService self;
  
  public void getCredit(String message) {
    self.isAccountConnectorUp();

    sendRequestToStream(message);
  }

  @Cacheable(value = "result", key = "#root.method.name", unless = "#result == true")
  public boolean isAccountConnectorUp() {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:9996/health";
    boolean isUp = false;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    try {
      String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
      isUp = true;
    } catch (ResourceAccessException exception) {
      throw new DatabaseException(ACCOUNT_CONNECTOR_IS_DOWN);
    }

    return isUp;
  }

}
```

If you really don't want to change the visibility and `static` nature of the method. Stop using proxy-based AOP and use compile-time weaving or load-time weaving to modify the bytecode of the class. However, this introduces complexity in either your build or how you need to start your application.

**NOTE:** Your caching doesn't work as there is `unless` clause. Which skips caching if the value is `true`, and exception won't be cached. So even with caching this won't work as nothing will be effectively cached.

Comment: I made my method public, removed `static` and injected a reference to myself and it still always enters isAccountConnectorUp every time.

Comment: If you read my answer and comment is that your caching isn't work due to your `unless` clause. So nothing will ever be cached.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Cacheable` will generate a proxy, but it will only work on the **public** method. Also, as mentioned in the comments, the proxy will not work on the **self-call** method.

Comment: I guess we can change it with CGLIB

Comment: yea, there is a property called `expose-proxy`, or something similar, that can do the hack.